# How can i decode binary text with Lua?

Tags: lua, binary, decode

Maybe someone got code for Binary decoder? I need it for my project, but i don't know how to code it. Thank you in advance

Comment: And what exactly is 'binary text' and to what do want to decode it? Can you give an example of this binary text and the expected result?

Comment: Lua strings are bytestrings. Just open files with `wb`/`rb` for reading/writing binary (usually doesn't matter on Unix, but matters on Windows). Do you want to read numbers encoded in binary? Which format are the numbers in? Signed/unsigned? Floating point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
Example...

```
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(tonumber('1111111111', 2))
1023
```